# Stuck in Paypal Integration

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate Paypal and I am not getting the things right.When the site is redirected to the Paypal,it shows the webpage(the image I have added with this Post).
Please anybody help me out of this mess coz I am doing this for the first.
Please anybody suggest me where I could be wrong.[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6920/captureqt.jpg](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6920/captureqt.jpg)

I have Used this Class to integrate Paypal to my site.But don't know why I am not getting the desired thing.

/*******************************************************************************
 *                      PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class

---

- Author:     Micah Carrick
- Email:      email@micahcarrick.com
- Website:    http://www.micahcarrick.com
  *
- File:       paypal.class.php
- Version:    1.3.0
- Copyright:  (c) 2005 - Micah Carrick
- You are free to use, distribute, and modify this software
- under the terms of the GNU General Public License.  See the
- included license.txt file.
- ---
- VERION HISTORY:
- v1.3.0 [10.10.2005] - Fixed it so that single quotes are handled the
- right way rather than simple stripping them.  This
- was needed because the user could still put in
- quotes.
- - v1.2.1 [06.05.2005] - Fixed typo from previous fix :)
    *
- v1.2.0 [05.31.2005] - Added the optional ability to remove all quotes
- from the paypal posts.  The IPN will come back
- invalid sometimes when quotes are used in certian
- fields.
  *
- v1.1.0 [05.15.2005] - Revised the form output in the submit_paypal_post
- method to allow non-javascript capable browsers
- to provide a means of manual form submission.
  *
- v1.0.0 [04.16.2005] - Initial Version
  *

  ---
- DESCRIPTION:
  *
- NOTE: See www.micahcarrick.com for the most recent version of this class
- along with any applicable sample files and other documentaion.
  *
- This file provides a neat and simple method to interface with paypal and
- The paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) interface.  This file is
- NOT intended to make the paypal integration "plug 'n' play". It still
- requires the developer (that should be you) to understand the paypal
- process and know the variables you want/need to pass to paypal to
- achieve what you want.
  *
- This class handles the submission of an order to paypal aswell as the
- processing an Instant Payment Notification.
- - This code is based on that of the php-toolkit from paypal.  I've taken
- the basic principals and put it in to a class so that it is a little
- easier--at least for me--to use.  The php-toolkit can be downloaded from
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/paypal.
- - To submit an order to paypal, have your order form POST to a file with:
    *
- $p = new paypal_class;
- $p->add_field('business', 'somebody@domain.com');
- $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
- ... (add all your fields in the same manor)
- $p->submit_paypal_post();
  *
- To process an IPN, have your IPN processing file contain:
  *
- $p = new paypal_class;
- if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
- ... (IPN is verified.  Details are in the ipn_data() array)
- }
  *
  *
- In case you are new to paypal, here is some information to help you:
  *
- 1. Download and read the Merchant User Manual and Integration Guide from
- http://www.paypal.com/en_US/pdf/integration_guide.pdf.  This gives
- you all the information you need including the fields you can pass to
- paypal (using add_field() with this class) aswell as all the fields
- that are returned in an IPN post (stored in the ipn_data() array in
- this class).  It also diagrams the entire transaction process.
  *
- 2. Create a "sandbox" account for a buyer and a seller.  This is just
- a test account(s) that allow you to test your site from both the
- seller and buyer perspective.  The instructions for this is available
- at https://developer.paypal.com/ as well as a great forum where you
- can ask all your paypal integration questions.  Make sure you follow
- all the directions in setting up a sandbox test environment, including
- the addition of fake bank accounts and credit cards.
- ---

*/

class paypal_class {

var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?

var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal

function paypal_class() {

```
  // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

  $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

  $this->last_error = '';

  $this->ipn_log_file = 'ipn_results.log';
  $this->ipn_log = true; 
  $this->ipn_response = '';

  // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
  // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
  // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

  $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
  $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick');
```

}

function add_field($field, $value) {

```
  // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
  // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
  // array, it will be overwritten.

  $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
```

}

function submit_paypal_post() {

```
  // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
  // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the 
  // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
  // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So 
  // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
  // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
  // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

  // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
  // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
  // is redirected to paypal.

  echo "<html>\n";
  echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
  echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
  echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
  echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
  echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
  echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

  foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
     echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
  }
  echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
  echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";

  echo "</form>\n";
  echo "</body></html>\n";
```

}
   //----------------------------------------
   // set status
   /*function setStatus()
   {

```
   $db = new Connection();
   $con = $db->getConnection();
   $query="insert into paypal_Result(`mc_gross`,`protection_eligibility`) values ('1','2')";
   $rs=mysql_query($query,$con);
   if($rs != "")
   {
      return true; 
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
```

}*/

//----------------------------------------

function validate_ipn() {

```
  // parse the paypal URL
  $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        

  // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
  // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
  // script.
  $post_string = '';    
  foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
     $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
     $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
  }
  $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

  // open the connection to paypal
  $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
  if(!$fp) {

     // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
     // will be in the log.
     $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
     $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
     return false;

  } else { 

     // Post the data back to paypal
     fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
     fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
     fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
     fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
     fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
     fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

     // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
     while(!feof($fp)) { 
        $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
     } 

     fclose($fp); // close connection

  }

  if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {

     // Valid IPN transaction.
     $this->log_ipn_results(true);
     return true;       

  } else {

     // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
     $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
     $this->log_ipn_results(false);   
     return false;

  }
```

}

function log_ipn_results($success) {

```
  if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

  // Timestamp
  $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 

  // Success or failure being logged?
  if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
  else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

  // Log the POST variables
  $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
  foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
     $text .= "$key=$value, ";
  }

  // Log the response from the paypal server
  $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

  // Write to log
  $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
  fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

  fclose($fp);  // close file
```

}

function dump_fields() {

```
  // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
  // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
  // add_field() function.

  echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
  echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
        <tr>
           <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
           <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
        </tr>"; 

  ksort($this->fields);
  foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
     echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
  }

  echo "</table><br>";
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with your code, but it is always good idea to use built-in classes to avoid any issues coming out of YOUR code, so i would suggest you to use this [paypal class](http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html) which will elevate a lot of efforts from your side.

Comment: hey thanks sarfaraz but I have used the same class to do this!

Comment: @Nishant: oh what a co-incidence ! well i saw your code but no idea where it is getting wrong, seems to be ok but :(

Comment: hey Sarfaraz,Well I rectified the bug I had in my code.But can I use any thing in the add_field.Like when paypal send the value back to our code I am trying to check by the help of some Values like
I am sending this Value to paypal
$p->add_field('type', 'admin')  
And the return values have to be saved in Database by checking if($_REQUEST['type'] == 'admin')
{ 
//-----My Logic----//
}
Is it allowed to send this field $p->add_field('type', 'admin') to Paypal?